# Ddb streams - will it invoke on a ddb.update() error?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say I have a lambda that calls ddb.update() and it fails. Will the TST 'new image' still be invoked, but with a null payload? Or will it not be invoked unless the ddb.update() succeeded?

Comment: DynamoDB Streams captures item-level modifications. I would not expect to see anything if no modification to an item occurred.

Answer (score 2):

The updates must succeed, and must also alter data.

- If it fails - No stream event
- If it succeeds, but did not change any values - No stream event.